# Propagators in Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, propagator

In what cases the time-independent Schrodinger equation can be used to construct the propagator?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators) help, if only for you to make the question more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, it is possible in all cases. Practically, it depends. The Schrödinger equation is:
$$\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\psi(t)\rangle.$$
The time evolution operator is defined by:
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \hat{U}(t)|\psi(0)\rangle.$$

So far, everything is completely general. If we have a basis, for example: $|x,m_s,s\rangle$ for $x$-position, $z$-component of spin, and total spin $s$, then we can construct the propagator as:
$$\langle x',m_s',s'|\hat{U}(t)|x,m_s,s\rangle.$$
In other words, the propagator is the matrix elements of the time evolution operator.

Now, suppose we know the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$:
$$\hat{H}|E,\alpha\rangle = E|E,\alpha\rangle,$$
where the energy levels are assumed here to be continuous, and $\alpha$ are the observable parameters needed to make $|E,\alpha\rangle$ a complete basis of the Hilbert space (e.g. the hydrogen atom has $|n,\ell,m,s,m_s\rangle$ with $n$ the principle quantum number that sets energy, and the angular momentum quantum numbers setting the degeneracy of each energy level). In this case, we can write the action of the time evolution operator on the energy eigenstates as
$$|E,\alpha,t\rangle = e^{-iEt/\hbar}|E,\alpha\rangle$$
if we assume the initial state matches with how we defined $|E,\alpha\rangle$. Because the energy eigenstates form a complete basis, this allows us to write the time tranlsation operator, formally, as:
$$\hat{U}(t) = \int \mathrm{d}E\mathrm{d}\alpha\, e^{-iEt/\hbar} |E,\alpha\rangle\langle E,\alpha|$$

If we further define the wave functions for the energy eigenstates as
$$\psi_{E,\alpha}(x,m_s,s) \equiv \langle x,m_s,s| E,\alpha\rangle$$
then the propagator becomes:
$$\langle x',m_s',s'|\hat{U}(t)|x,m_s,s\rangle = \int\mathrm{d}E\mathrm{d}\alpha\, e^{-iEt/\hbar} \psi_{E,\alpha}^*(x',m_s',s')\, \psi_{E,\alpha}(x,m_s,s).$$

The issue now becomes: for a given $\psi_{E,\alpha}(x,m_s,s)$ can you actually evaluate (or at least approximate) that integral? If the energy levels are quantized, then that part of the integral becomes a sum (similarly for the other quantum numbers $\alpha$), but an infinite sum is not necessarily any easier to approximate than an integral. In fact, I know of only three cases where explicit propagators have been worked out analytically: magnetic resonance (i.e. a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field - the energies are discrete and the number of states is finite), a free particle, and the simple harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Your first sentence reads: "Formally, yes." But OP did not pose a yes or no question. So, it is a little unclear what this means. I think you mean "Formally, yes, it is possible to construct the propagator from the time-dependent Schrodinger equation" or "Formally, yes, it is possible to construct the propagator from the time-dependent Schrodinger equation in all cases." A modification like this can clarify your answer at the present and perhaps more importantly in the future should OP edit the question. I also like to quote OP in case their future edit change their question entirely.